# Is there a nesting levels limit with expressions used in SSIS packages? 

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, ssis

Working in SQL Server 2008.  My first stab at an SSIS script and I need to emulate some if/then conditional logic written in VB.net.  I couldn't find any previous questions dealing with nested conditions in expressions and believe I'm following what I've been able to uncover via google on nested conditions in a derived column.

I'm receiving an error while attempting to use nested conditions in the derived column transformation editor.  The error I'm receiving indicates that SSIS could not parse my expression.  The actual exception: "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)"

Questions for which the answers might immediately answer my question (and create a new problem):

- is there a nesting levels limit?
- can nesting be performed in the condition1 portion of [expression] ? [condition1] : [condition2]

I'll give two snippets, the first is what I'm actually inserting, the second is a more reader-friendly version.  Hopefully someone can point out my error.

Not sure that it has bearing, but please note that [BusArea] is a column derived in a previous step.

actual expression:

```
[BusArea] == "CCC" || [BusArea] == "NBU" || [BusArea] == "CA" ? (ISNULL([CASE_MORG]) or TRIM([CASE_MORG]) == "" ? ( ISNULL([TRX_MORG]) or TRIM([TRX_MORG]) == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [TRX_MORG]) : [CASE_MORG]) : (ISNULL([CASE_AGT]) or TRIM([CASE_AGT]) == "" ? ( ISNULL([TRX_AGT]) or TRIM([TRX_AGT]) == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : [TRX_AGT]) : [CASE_AGT])
```

formatted for easier reading:

```
[BusArea] == "CCC" || [BusArea] == "NBU" || [BusArea] == "CA" ? 
    (ISNULL([CASE_MORG]) or TRIM([CASE_MORG]) == "" ?
        ( ISNULL([TRX_MORG]) or TRIM([TRX_MORG]) == "" ?
            NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
            : [TRX_MORG]
        )
        : [CASE_MORG]
    )
    : (ISNULL([CASE_AGT]) or TRIM([CASE_AGT]) == "" ?
        ( ISNULL([TRX_AGT]) or TRIM([TRX_AGT]) == "" ?
            NULL(DT_WSTR,50)
            : [TRX_AGT]
        )
        : [CASE_AGT]
    )
```

Comment: Two bits of advice: When the expressions get this long, it's sometimes easier to push the logic into a script task. As a general rule, use the native transformations until they become too unwieldy. The other option which leads to better performance is to break it across multiple derived column transformations. The Engine can better parallelize operations in small, discrete transforms than everything and the kitchen sink in 1-2 transforms. This also makes debugging slightly easier as data viewers attached can provide insight into intermediate values.

Comment: As a potential solution: I've had issues with the ternary operator where I was attempting to cast a NULL version as one of the options. I believe I had to cast the entire result to the appropriate type, even though it *should* have figured it out based on the inner types. So, try something like `(DT_WSTR, 50) ([BusArea]...)`

Comment: I did try declaring the data type as suggested, but was unable to get it working.  I moved all of it to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any limit with nesting conditions. Even if there is one, I don't think we will reach the limit in the packages that we create handle our business processes.

You almost got everything correct. The issue with your conditional statement is that you have used **`or`** instead of **`||`**

I copied your exact statement and pasted in `Derived Transformation` within a `Data Flow task` and got an error because the package couldn't parse the expression. I replaced all the **`or's`** with correct **Logical OR** (**`||`**) operator and the expression evaluated correctly.

[image: Issue with conditional statement]

Comment: hey thanks!  where were you two months ago?  I never did catch that.